# Double function in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I try to learn Isabelle/HOL by working through [this](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/prog-prove.pdf) tutorial. I have a problem with the exercise about the double function. I defined it like this:

```
fun double :: "nat ⇒ nat" where 
"double 0 = add 0 0" |
"double (Suc m) = Suc(Suc (double m))"
```

But when trying to prove that double m = add m m in my theorem:

```
theorem add_d [simp] : "double x = add x x"
apply(induction x)
apply(auto)
done
```

apply(auto) never gets evaluated (it's background is pink(?)). The same exercise asks to prove the commutativity and associativity of add and this worked ok. I am using Isabelle2014 with the default (Jedit) IDE.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour under Isabelle 2014. Could you try to give a minimal complete example, i.e. a full theory file that just contains the error?

Comment: Here is an example http://pastebin.com/UWHsKUpg. The problem is in line 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code from your comment many theorems have `[simp]` attribute that tells Isabelle to add them to the simpset. However some of them are not suitable as a rewriting rule (used by `simp` and by `auto`), because they lead to a term to which the same rule can be applied again, causing an infinite loop. Removing the offending theorem from the simpset does the trick:

```
theorem add_d: "double x = add x x"
  apply (induction x)
  apply (auto simp del: add_zero)
done
```

But a better solution is to avoid adding such theorems to the simpset in the first place, e.g. to remove `[simp]` attribute from their declaration:

```
lemma add_zero: "add x 0 = add 0 x"
  apply (induction x)
  apply (auto)
done
```

After that `add_d` does not need the `simp del` part. But some other theorems may need to be explicitly told to use this particular rule, e.g. this one:

```
theorem add_com: "add x y = add y x"
  apply (induction x)
  apply (auto simp add: add_zero)
done
```

Note that, compared to your code, the `[simp]` attribute is dropped again to avoid circular rewriting if `add_com` is used elsewhere.

Comment: Now it works (keeping add2 in the simp class). Seems that in fact I had an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

While Alexander's advice about simp-rules is sound, let me give some further comments.

Firstly, in your definition of `double`, I would replace `add 0 0` by `0`. As a general advice: *prefer simple expressions over complex ones*.

Secondly, Isabelle's simplifier is actually "smart" enough to handle rewriting with AC (i.e., associativity and commutativity) without looping, i.e., your two lemmas

```
lemma add_assoc [simp]:
  "add (add x y) z = add x (add y z)"
```

and

```
lemma add_commute [simp]:
  "add x y = add y x"
```

are fine as simp-rules (i.e., you can keep the `[simp]` attribute). The cause of the loop you are experiencing is your lemma

```
(*BAD*)
lemma add_zero [simp]:
  "add x 0 = add 0 x"
```

Since having it in the *simpset* (Isabelle jargon for the set of all simplification rules that are used by methods like `simp` and `auto`) allows for the infinite derivation:

```
add 0 0 = add 0 0 = add 0 0 = ...
```

I would suggest to replace it by

```
lemma add_zero [simp]:
  "add x 0 = x"
```

Then all your proofs (provided they are stated in the correct order) should be "automatic" in the sense

```
apply (induction ...)
apply auto
done
```

which can be abbreviated to

```
by (induction ...) (auto)
```